# Can decltype be used to determine type of the arguments?

Tags: c++, c++11, eigen, decltype

I am working with expression templates and want to determine type of the expression argument. Expressions have mangled names with lots of template parameters, but their type can be simply deduced from the type of arguments. **Is there some trick which can help me determine type of the expression based on the operation used to produce it?**

```
template<typename X1, typename X2>
void foo(decltype(x1() + x2())) {}
```

note: I'm trying to add automatic differentiation for Eigen.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, and just make them upper case:

```
template<typename X1, typename X2>
void foo(decltype(X1() + X2()) x) {}
```

In addition, you can use [`std::common_type`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type):

```
template<typename X1, typename X2>
void foo(typename std::common_type<X1,X2>::type x) {}
```

How ever it's a bit weird and you should call `foo` like below:

```
foo<int, float>(12.5);
```

It's more useful to deduce the return type:

```
template<typename X1, typename X2>
auto foo(X1 x1, X2 x2) -> typename std::common_type<X1,X2>::type
{
    return x1 + x2;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But calling foo explicitly specifying arguments types doesn't really solve the problem, because arguments can be itself expressions.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned about that. You should just pass it by one template placeholder: `template<typename X> void foo(X x) {}`.

Comment: In that case any expression will suit the overload. But I need different functions to be called for foo(x + y) and foo(x - y).

Comment: `x + y` and `x - y` will generate same result types.

Comment: x and y are not just ints or floats. They are objects with overloaded +,-,*,/ etc. that generate expression objects: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_templates

Comment: Better `decltype(x1+x2)` should be used as trailing-return-type.